# "Default displacement = 0, consider adjusting" Error when applying materials

Tags: materials

I'm using blender 2.82a

I've been sculpting in VR programs such as Oculus Medium and importing to blender to add lighting and material shading.  Its's been working great, I've been using materials from Poliigon.com. However, after importing some background elements I created in Gravity Sketch, I cannot seem to get materials to apply properly to those meshes.

I imported from Gravity Sketch into blender (saved as .obj) and then separated the objects, since they came in all as one group (edit mode, select all, Select mesh menu->Vertices->Separate->by loose parts).  **When I apply a material to one of those meshes, I get a yellow error message at the bottom of the screen saying "Default displacement = 0, consider adjusting"** and I don't know how to proceed.

[image]

Any advice on what I'm missing here would help.  I tried unwrapping the meshes and that did not work. Here is the file if that helps. The objects in question are the slide, sandbox bricks and the swing set.

Thanks very much!
-Brock

[blender file with the issue](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kjfjap923xgd9r5/Materia_Girls_15.blend?dl=0)

Comment: i had the same problem. i was using Polygon Material Converter addon, but using Material Library Vx I can use textures and no displacement error appears

Answer (score 0):

[image]
I'm new at this too, I had the same issue today and I spent 30 minutes figuring out what's going on. I see you're using the Poliigon nodes too.

No matter how much I tweaked the actual Displacement node, nothing was displaced.
I only saw the sliders under 2 after half an hour, displacement was visible after moving the Displacement Strength to something else than 0, see my rendered view in the screenshot.

However, I see you don't actually have those sliders in your material custom block. Does your texture have a displacement map in it's folder? Maybe you didn't include it in your download?

Answer (score 0):

*Render Properties* and set render engine to cycles and feature set to experimental, then go to *Material Properties* and add a new material for your object. Finally, in the *Material Properties* go to *Settings -> Surface* and then set Displacement to "Displacement and Bump".